# How to avoid keyboard from moving my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-input-method

Every time I get in the Activity, the keyboard layout moves. I want the fields to remain below the keyboard, and you use the scroll. 
I think that may be something with the actionbar.

See hera a print [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm9xG.png)

I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` with no success.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bruno.gpmap.manage.Register">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/cad_register_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/register_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pick_date"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:entries="@array/gender"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use only  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the specific activity in  your Manifest file.

```
<activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not working because you are using a `ScrollView`.

Use `android:isScrollContainer="false"` on the `ScrollView`

Comment: did not work, i think that there is something with the action bar

Comment: it also needs `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for your Activity in Manifest